# Is it possible in RabbitMQ to have a callback which is a consumer and a producer at the same time? If yes, is it a good approach?

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq

I have one queue where I send my messages. When a consumer receives a message from that queue, it will process it and generate number of specific messages that need to be send to another queue. Then I will have a number of consumers to process those messages.

Is it proper way to do this? If yes, do I just define this callback class as a consumer and a producer at the same time? I am using [RabbitMqBundle](https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle) for symfony.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds pretty normal.

Producers and consumers are separate classes. When you are using RabbitMqBundle producer service is autogenerated by the bundle and you can inject it to other classes eg. consumers. (https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle#producer)
The service name for producer will start with old_sound_rabbit_mq.[PRODUCER_NAME].